# Android crash report shows exception that is caught

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app written in Java, and recently noticed many crash reports occurring in an AsyncTask. The stack trace makes no sense, as it is inside a try/catch so there is no way for the exception to be thrown. How can a caught exception cause an app crash?

```
13: public class HttpGoogleSignInAction...
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            // Check if user exists
            UserConfig user = null;
31:         user = MainActivity.connection.fetch(this.config);

            if (user == null) {

            } else {
                // User exists, try to sign in user
                this.config = MainActivity.connection.connect(this.config);
            }
        } catch (Exception userDoesNotExist) {
            try {
                // User does not exist, try to create user
                this.config = MainActivity.connection.create(this.config);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                this.exception = exception;
            }
        }
        return "";
    }


public String POST(String url, String xml) {
    if (this.debug) {
        System.out.println("POST: " + url);
        System.out.println("XML: " + xml);
    }
    String result = "";
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        
        StringEntity content = new StringEntity(xml, "utf-8");
        content.setContentType("application/xml");
        httpPost.setEntity(content);
        
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            result = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);
        }

        if ((response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) && (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 204)) {
            this.exception = new SDKException(""
               + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
               + " : " + result);
2205:       throw this.exception;
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        if (this.debug) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.exception = new SDKException(exception);
2213:       throw this.exception;
    }
    return result;
}
```

The stack trace shows the crash occurring in the line,

```
user = MainActivity.connection.fetch(this.config);
```

It is a normal RuntimeException subclass exception being thrown, which should be caught. If I try to force an exception to test it the try/catch works fine and no crash, but in 1% of users using the app I am seeing crashes, others it works fine.
Makes no sense.

This is the stack trace from Google Play, SDKException is a subclass of RuntimeException, the line of code it occurs in is inside try/catch

```
org.botlibre.sdk.SDKException: 
  at org.botlibre.sdk.SDKConnection.POST (SDKConnection.java:2213)
  at org.botlibre.sdk.SDKConnection.fetch (SDKConnection.java:259)
  at ...HttpGoogleSignInAction.doInBackground (HttpGoogleSignInAction.java:31)
  at ...HttpGoogleSignInAction.doInBackground (HttpGoogleSignInAction.java:13)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call (AsyncTask.java:394)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:305)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)
Caused by: org.botlibre.sdk.SDKException: 
  at org.botlibre.sdk.SDKConnection.POST (SDKConnection.java:2205)
```

Comment: Is it the same app version? Does it happen in a different thread (AsyncTask creates one)? - Exceptions in different threads are not caught. Can you reproduce it (not the result, but the exception) / is it a UserDoesNotExistException or something unexpected? Why do you have a Void[] as a method parameter?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Is the `RuntimeExceotion` the top exception or an inner cause (that "caused by" thing). Not every `Throwable` is `Exception`

Comment: Also, I see that you save an exception in `this.exception`. maybe you're throwing `this.exception` somewhere else?

Comment: it is a subclass of RuntimeException, the this.exception is never thrown, occurs on multiple app versions, AsyncTask does run on another thread but try/catch in doInBackground traps the exception, testing throwing the same error, it is caught correctly

Comment: If I don't miss anything, the `org.botlibre.sdk.SDKException` exception should be caught there. Like @Cactusroot mentioned maybe the exception is thrown in the older versions of the app, where there is no `try-catch` block. It would be great, If you could post the code according to the exception lines in the stack trace, e.g. `at ...HttpGoogleSignInAction.doInBackground (HttpGoogleSignInAction.java:13)` line 13 should correspond to the line of your code posted in the question.

Comment: `doInBackground` appears twice, could you explain?

Comment: Where did you got that SDK from? POST is not even on the same line in github's source: https://github.com/BotLibre/BotLibre/blob/master/sdk/android/BotLibre/app/src/main/java/org/botlibre/sdk/SDKConnection.java

Comment: Using a newer version, I added the line numbers to the code above.

Comment: Seems to be failing from some primitive network failure as from exception message the status code and result must have both been empty

Comment: hmmm, could be possible this.exception it getting used

Comment: You are throwing a new `Exception` inside `catch` on the line 2213 which is not handled. See @Tenfour04 's answer

Answer (score 1):

```
org.botlibre.sdk.SDKException: 
  at org.botlibre.sdk.SDKConnection.POST (SDKConnection.java:2213)
  at org.botlibre.sdk.SDKConnection.fetch (SDKConnection.java:259)
```

Shows that you're throwing the exception captured here in `doInBackground()`:

```
try {
                // User does not exist, try to create user
                this.config = MainActivity.connection.create(this.config);
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                **this.exception = exception;**
            }
        }
```

Even though this execption is within a catch block, since it's persisted and then thrown later it is now outside of a try-catch block and can crash the app. That is

```
try {
...
} catch (Exception exception) {
        if (this.debug) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.exception = new SDKException(exception);
// This line will throw an execption that will have the message from the original exception. 
2213:       throw this.exception;
    }
```

The source for SDKException's single exception constructor shows it reuses the message from the exception parameter.

Comment: the POST is called from fetch() called from doInBackground inside a try/catch. This exception is caught. I think the issue is the exception stored in the instance variable is getting thrown elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You are very clearly *re-throwing* the caught exception on line 2213. If you `throw` an exception from a `catch` block, it escapes the try/catch because you are throwing it from a scope of code that is not surrounded by `try { }`.

As for why `fetch()` might be throwing, we would have to see the code to be able to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have your code wrapped in try catch, there is a possibility of a crash if different threads are involved. try catch does not catch exceptions from child threads, so if any of your methods(like .fetch or .connect) used in doInBackground are internally using/creating different threads and an exception is thrown within that thread it might cause the app to crash. Looking at the logs, it is possible the .fetch method is asynchronous and performing operations in a different thread.

Comment: If the exception occurred on another thread, shouldn't it show up as a different exception/stack in the crash log?

Comment: What is there in the fetch method in the line `MainActivity.connection.fetch(this.config)` ?

Comment: The fetch calls the POST method, the exception occurs because of a network failure I assume in the http calls.